# Detect that the file exists

Tags: java, file

Please how to detect that the file exists and don't create a new one each time I run it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file.tmp");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject("12345");
    oos.writeObject("Today");

    oos.close();

}
```

Comment: Had you gone through the documentation of `File` class, you would have found : - [`File#exists`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
File f = new File("file.tmp");
if(f.exists()) {
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`File.exits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29):

```
File f = new File("file.tmp");// this does not create a file

if (f.exists()) {
    System.out.println("File existed");
} else {
    System.out.println("File not found!");
}
```

Then you can even use the constructor `FileOutputStream(File f, boolean append)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
public boolean settingsFileExits(final String fileName) {
    File f = new File(fileName);
    return f.exists();
}
```

Comment: Why the ternary operator and not just "return f.exists();"?

Comment: L0L, you are right! :D I did not see that coming ... Thanks for correction!

Answer (score 0):

Use File class API:

[File.exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `FileOutputStream` use `File` class then do

if file.exists()

And

Instead of asking immediately in stack over flow, google it.